# Elixi Phoenix : category_controller.ex:7: MagazijnWeb.Category.__struct__/1 is undefined,

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

The error is:

```
lib/magazijn_web/controllers/category_controller.ex:7: MagazijnWeb.Category.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct MagazijnWeb.Category. Make sure the struct name is correct. If the struct name exists and is correct but it still cannot be found, you likely have cyclic module usage in your code
```

Here is the code:

```
defmodule MagazijnWeb.CategoryController do
  use MagazijnWeb, :controller

  alias MagazijnWeb.Category

  def new(conn,params) do
    changeset = Category.changeset(%Category{}, %{})
    render conn,"new.html"
  end

  def create(conn,_params) do
    
  end
end
```

I created the model directly under MagazijnWeb (the project):

```
defmodule Category do
    use Ecto.Schema
    import Ecto.Changeset

    schema "category" do
        field :category, :string
    end

    def changeset(category, params \\ %{}) do
        category
        |> cast(params,[:category])
        |> validate_required([:category])
    end
end
```

thanks

Comment: Is it really `defmodule Category do` instead of `defmodule MagazijnWeb.Category do`? Besides, we shouldn't find the `Web` suffix on the model/schema.

Comment: Check out [`mix phx.gen.html`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Html.html).

Comment: This was resolved on Elixir Forum https://elixirforum.com/t/magazijnweb-category-struct-1-is-undefined-cannot-expand-struct-magazijnweb-category/46282/6?u=adamu

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the `MagazijnWeb` in the `Category` module definition. To use it like you are trying to it should be `defmodule MagazijnWeb.Category do`. However, `Category` really doesn't belong in the web context so I would probably put this under `magazijn` and not `magazijn_web` and then you would do `defmodule Magazijn.Category do`.